# Speed and Distance

Tags: derivatives

Suppose the following reading:

Odometer = 1 km
Speedometer = 1 km/hr.

The driver accelerates in such a way that both remain the same.

Is there a situation where both can remain the same ?

Can a function of distance wrt time be given?
Can a function of speed wrt time be given?

What would be the speed after 100 kms on odometer?

Answer (score 3):

Solve for distance $= f(t) = f'(t) = $ speed.  You can use initial conditions $f(0) = 1$ (why?) to get a very familiar function.

To answer your question on what the speed will be when the odometer reads $100$, you know by definition these readings are going to be equal.